# Which (free) graph/chart package has 3d line graph for Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graph, charts, google-analytics

Google API doesn't have it. 
Does anyone know free package with this feature?
Here's an example what I need:
http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2013.1/CLR4.0/html/Images/Chart_Line_Chart_02.png

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using D3 http://d3js.org/ for advanced graphs or jqplot http://www.jqplot.com/‎

Comment: If you have that skills you can create them d3. no? 3D graph libraries are li'l harder to find.

Answer (score 0):

You can also refer to the following http://www.advsofteng.com/cdruby.html and http://www.fusioncharts.com/products/suite/?gclid=CMbHrqa0yLkCFa0l4godzGMAyg

Comment: These are commercial libraries.